# Missing default "Sent Messages" IMAP folder

Tags: node.js, imap

I'm using the excellent [inbox](https://github.com/andris9/inbox) node.js library and for certain email accounts I'm not seeing some of the default Mailboxes, such as "Sent Messages". I'm pretty much using the example code as-is with OAUTH2;

```
client = inbox.createConnection(false, "imap.gmail.com", {
    secureConnection: true,
    auth: {
        XOAuth2: {
            user: account.email,
            clientId: Settings.googleApp.clientId,
            clientSecret: Settings.googleApp.secretId,
            refreshToken: refreshToken,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            timeout: expires
        }
    }
});

client.connect();

client.on("connect", function() {

    Logger.debug("Opening mailbox " + mailbox);

    self.getMailboxes(function(err, boxes){
        var boxNames = _.pluck(boxes, 'name');
        Logger.info(boxNames);
    });
}
```

I'm a little stumped....

Comment: The mailbox is in the [Gmail] heirarchy, and may be localized.  In English, it's called "[Gmail]/Sent Messages"

Comment: After a brief glance at the inbox documentation, I'll hazard a guess that you want to look at the mailbox type. Find the mailbox with the right type. What's the right type? Well, perhaps the library is excellent, but that documentation isn't ;)

Comment: Thanks, I found the "[Gmail]/Sent Messages" folder, which is a child mailbox for "All Messages" I think. I just thought that the IMAP spec specified the default mailbox of "Sent Messages" should exists, and its weird that for some Gmail accounts it does, but not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, so I ended up using the type (type='Sent') and iterated through all the child mailboxes to pull out all the Sent mailboxes, which allows for locale specific names for the mailbox. Here is the code;

```
        client.listMailboxes(function(error, mailboxes){

            var _findSent = function(mailbox, callback){

                if(mailbox.hasChildren){

                    mailbox.listChildren(function(error, children){

                        var sent = [];

                        for(var i=0; i < children.length; i++){

                            if (children[i].type == 'Sent'){
                                sent.push(children[i]);
                            }
                        }

                        callback(null, sent);

                    });

                }
                else {

                    var sent = [];

                    if (mailbox.type == 'Sent'){
                        sent.push(mailbox);
                    }

                    callback(null, sent);
                }

            }


            async.map(mailboxes, _findSent, function(err, results){
                onGotSentMailboxes(_.flatten(results));
            });

        });
```